# How to copy current directory into Drupal profile folder via drush?

Tags: drush, installation-profiles

I've this yml file in my current folder:

```
$ cat profile.yml 
api: 2
core: 7.x
projects:
  drupal7:
    type: "copy"
    download:
      url: "file://."
```

and 3 empty files (just for now): `drupal7.info`, `drupal7.install`, `drupal7.profile`.

And I've downloaded fresh Drupal:

```
$ drush -y dl drupal
Project drupal (7.39) downloaded to drupal-7.39.
```

Now I'm trying to copy my profile into Drupal directory via:

```
$ drush make --no-core profile.yml drupal-7.39/
Beginning to build profile.yml.
Non-existent project type copy on project drupal7.
```

and the same with:

```
$ drush make -r drupal-7.39/ --yes --no-core profile.yml
```

This is based on [this](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/) example:

```
projects[example][type] = "profile"
projects[example][download][type] = "copy"
projects[example][download][url] = "file://./example"
```

but I'd like to achieve that in yml format.

What is the correct syntax then? Or how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to specify extra `type: "profile"` (to follow [this](http://www.drush.org/en/master/make/) example), so `type` is specified twice (type of project, and type of download), as below:

```
api: 2
core: 7.x
projects:
  drupal7:
    type: "profile"
    download:
      type: "copy"
      url: "file://."
```

Then this would work fine:

```
$ drush make --no-core profile.yml drupal-7.39/
Beginning to build profile.yml.
drupal7 copied from file://..
```

To avoid copying `docroot/` it-self, it's good to actually create a separate folder for profile (as specifying wildcard won't work).